# What is the difference between setting a bit and writing logic one to a bit?

Tags: c, embedded, bit-manipulation

I am studying TWI of Atmel ATMega and the example code bug me. It say that the interrupt flag TWINT must be cleared by writing logic one to it so I suppose that it is like this in C to send START condition

```
TWCR |= (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN)
```

However in the example code it is like this

```
TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA|(1<<TWEN)
```

It is also said in the Atmel page that `TWCR |=(1<<TWINT)` is wrong way to clear interrupt flag  http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/FAQ_1faq_intbits.html
so what make it different between setting a bit and writing to a bit since it is wrong to use `TWCR |=(1<<TWINT)`

I am using datasheet of Atmel 2549 8-bit microcontroller. The example code is taken from section 24.6

Comment: This is a good question.  It arises from the "write 1 clear" behavior of certain types of hardware registers, which is fairly common in the hardware interface world, but can be an unfamiliar surprise for those from a more everyday software background.   Please keep this detail in mind before voting on the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to properly write to registers is done by case to case basis. The link you refer to speak of *interrupt flag registers* that are cleared by writing a 1.

Assume you have the 8 bit register `REG` with two flags. You want to clear the lsb flag. If you write

```
#define FLAG0 0x01
#define FLAG1 0x02
...
REG = FLAG0;
```

Then this will translate to machine code "in REG, write value 1 to bit 0", which correctly clears the flag.

If you however do `REG |= FLAG0`, then the program will first read the register and store the read value in a temporary location. Suppose the register has value 0x03, both flags set. Your code will write 0x01 to this  temporary location, but because of the bitwise OR it will also preserve the value of other, non-related flags. So you end up writing back the value 0x03 to `REG`, clearing both the desired flag and an unrelated flag.

Interrupt flag registers are very delicate, because they can be implemented through all kinds of weird logic that doesn't go well together with C programming, such as "clear by writing 1" or "clear by read with flag set". Therefore, I strongly recommend the practice to always disassemble C code that clears such flags, and check to see what the code actually does.

Answer (score 2):

The |= assignment is a read-modify-write operation, but not all hardware registers behave like memory locations - in this case the bit values are set by hardware and read and/or cleared by software.  Writing by software does not store the value written, but in the case of these bits clears the bit.  Other bits in TWCR have different behaviour, but none can be set to a specific value and writing zero to any of them has no effect.

Therefore the read-modify-write is unnecessary, and *incorrect* - it may cause the clearing of a bit unintentionally.

That is  why the documentation is careful about the term "writing logic one", because it specifically does not "set the bit" - it clears it.

Answer (score 1):

The [linked FAQ](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/FAQ_1faq_intbits.html) is pretty clear (the last paragraph is the important part) - you only need to set relevant interrupt bits in this register to 1 in order to clear interrupts (setting bits to 0 has no effect). So there is no need to preserve the state of other bits, and using a write rather than read-modify-write will avoid a potential race condition that can arise between the read cycle and the write cycle.

Comment: But the question is why the Atmel docs state that you *shouldn't* do the first version.